# Is it possible to check if a subset of a dictionary comes from a main dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, spacy, spacy-3

I am working on a NLP process using spaCy and trying to get the results of one dictionary (result of an analysis) to cross check against the full dictionary (pre-determined by me). I am trying to take a sentence, run it through spaCy, and see if it contains all of the requirements to be considered a proper English sentence.

I tried 2 different methods, neither of which worked.

Sets my_phrase

```
my_phrase = nlp(u"It is a beautiful day today.")
```

**Method 1**

Checks the POS for the sentence

```
for word in my_phrase:
  print(f'{word.text:{12}} {word.pos_:{10}} {word.tag_:{8}} {spacy.explain(word.tag_)}')
```

Creates the dictionary

```
my_phrase_ = defaultdict()
for _, value in enumerate(my_phrase):
  key = "part_of_speech: " + value.pos_
  my_phrase_[key] = value
```

Subsets the POS I want to check for

```
english_sent = {
    "DET": "Determiner",
    "NOUN": "Noun",
    "PRON": "Pronoun",
    "PROPN": "Proper Noun",
    "VERB": "Verb",
}
```

Prints the two dictonaries

```
print(english_sent)
print(my_phrase_)
```

Check to see if at least one of each of the required POS from english_sent are in the my_phrase_ dictionary

```
def checkKey(english_sent, my_phrase_):
    if my_phrase in english_sent:
        print("Present, ", end =" ")
        print("value =", english_sent[my_phrase_])
    else:
        print("Not present")


checkKey(english_sent, my_phrase_)
```

It always returns "Not present"; I even tried flipping the dictionary so the full words were the key and the abbreviations were the values.

**Method 2**

I also tried a simple if statement but that did not work either

```
if "NOUN" and "PRON" and "VERB" and "DET" in my_phrase_:
    print("Valid statement")
```

This does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

The keys for `my_phrase_` are weird - they're like `part of speech: NOUN` when they should be like `NOUN`. You should change your code to be like this:

```
my_phrase_ = defaultdict()
for _, value in enumerate(my_phrase):
  my_phrase_[value.pos_] = value
```